Cannot invoke "com.example.service.PersonService.save(Object)" because "this.personService" is null
I have a personal program that uses Springboot and Javafx. I've been trying to gain more skills in creating springboot and javafx apps. Program launches an fxml page where a person can update a person's records, clicks save, and is then saved to an mssql database.
I'm trying to save a new person record to a mssql database.
PersonEntity.java
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@Data
@Table(name = "persons")
public class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "personID", nullable = false)
    private final Integer personID;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @Setter
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @Setter
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "dob")
    @Setter
    private String dob;

PersonRepo.java
@Repository
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, String> {
    List<PersonEntity> findAll();
}

PersonService.java
public interface PersonService{
    Optional<PersonEntity> save(PersonEntity personEntity);
    PersonEntity update(PersonEntity personEntity);
    PersonEntity findAll();
   
}

PersonServiceImpl.java

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonServiceImplimplements PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepo repo;

    @Override
    public Optional<PersonEntity> save(PersonEntity personEntity) {
        return Optional.of(repo.save(personEntity));
    }

    @Override
    public PersonEntity update(PersonEntity personEntity){ return repo.save(personEntity);}

    @Override
    public PersonEntity findAll() {
        return (PersonEntity ) repo.findAll();
    }
}


PersonController.java
@Component
public class PersonController {
 @Autowired
 PersonService personService;
 public TextField lName;
 public TextField fName;
 public TextField dob;
 public Button onSaveNewPerson;

   @FXML
    public void onSaveNewPerson(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
        if(fName != null){
            PersonEntity newPerson = new PersonEntity ();
            fName.setText(newPerson.getFirstName());
            personService.save(newPerson);

        }
}

PersonsRecord.fxml
<AnchorPane fx:id="scenePane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.controllers.PersonController">
    <Pane layoutX="-2.0" layoutY="91.0" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1004.0">
        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" text="New Person Form">
           <font>
               <Font size="20.0"/>
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="69.0" text="First Name"/>
        <Label layoutX="16.0" layoutY="130.0" text="Last name"/>
        <Label layoutX="18.0" layoutY="130.0" text="Date of Birth"/>
        <Label layoutX="20.0" layoutY="130.0" text="Address"/>
        <TextField fx:id="fName" layoutX="98.0" layoutY="66.0"/>
        <TextField fx:id="lName" layoutX="98.0" layoutY="126.0"/>
        <TextField fx:id="dob" layoutX="98.0" layoutY="146.0"/>
        <TextField fx:id="personAddress" layoutX="98.0" layoutY="166.0"/>
        <Button fx:id="saveNewPerson" layoutX="803.0" layoutY="333.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                onAction="#onSaveNewPerson" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="187.0" text="Save New Person"/>
        <Label layoutX="597.0" layoutY="70.0" text="DOB"/>
        <TextField fx:id="dob" layoutX="691.0" layoutY="66.0"/>
    </Pane>
</AnchorPane>

Currently after clicking the onSaveNewPersonbutton I receive the following error -
Cannot invoke "com.example.services.PersonService.save(com.example.entity.persons.PersonEntity)" because "this.personService" is null
I do want all the textfields to save but for right now I've just been testing with the fname field.
I've ensured the @Autowired is set for the personService in the controller. I also made sure the @Repository is set for the PersonRepo.
I also added the implements CommandLineRunner to the FxApplication file and had a test person added to the database to ensure proper connectivity. That ran just fine and a person was entered successfully. Code for investigation -
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repo")
public class FxApplication extends Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent root;
    @Autowired
    PersonRepo personRepo;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(FxApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/PersonsRecord.fxml"));
      
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
        stage.setTitle("Add NewPerson");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception{
      springContext = SpringApplication.run(FxApplication.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception{
        springContext.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        PersonEntity person = new PersonEntity ();
        person.setFirstName("TestSpring3");
        person.setLastName("LastNameTest4");
        person.setDOB("1/1/2000")
        personRepo.save(person);

    }
}

I edited my code and used the template that was provided via @David Weber.
This is now my FxApplicationLauncher.java class that I have edited.
package com.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.HostServices;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.*;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repo")
public class FxApplicationLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(FxApplication.class, args);
    }
    public static class FxApplication extends Application {
        private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
        @Override
        public void init(){
            ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> initializer = applicationContext -> {
                applicationContext.registerBean(Application.class, () -> FxApplication.this);
                applicationContext.registerBean(Parameters.class, this::getParameters);
                applicationContext.registerBean(HostServices.class, this::getHostServices);
            };

            this.context = new SpringApplicationBuilder()
                    .sources(FxApplicationLauncher.class)
                    .initializers(initializer)
                    .run(getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]));
        }
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage)  { this.context.publishEvent(new StageIsReadyEvent(stage)); }

        @Override
        public void stop() throws Exception {
            context.close();
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        @Component
        public static class FxApplicationStageIsReadyListener implements ApplicationListener<StageIsReadyEvent>{
            @Value("${spring.application.name}")
            private  String applicationTitle;
            private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

            public void JfxSpringBootStageIsReadyListener(
                    @Value("${spring.application.name}") String applicationTitle,
                    ApplicationContext applicationContext) {

                this.applicationTitle = applicationTitle;
                this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(StageIsReadyEvent event) {
                try {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/PersonsRecord.fxml"));
                    fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);                
                    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();

                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
                    Stage stage = event.getStage();               
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.setTitle(this.applicationTitle);
                    stage.show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

        }

        public static class StageIsReadyEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
            public Stage getStage() {
                return (Stage) getSource();
            }

            public StageIsReadyEvent(Stage source) {
                super(source);
            }
        }

    }
}

For some reason the applicationContext is null.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
at com.example.gaitlabapp.FxApplicationLauncher$FxApplication$FxApplicationStageIsReadyListener.onApplicationEvent(FxApplicationLauncher.java:84)
at com.example.gaitlabapp.FxApplicationLauncher$FxApplication$FxApplicationStageIsReadyListener.onApplicationEvent(FxApplicationLauncher.java:65)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:384)
at com.example.gaitlabapp.FxApplicationLauncher$FxApplication.start(FxApplicationLauncher.java:51)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)


can you add to your question the entire stacktrace of the error please? when a bean is not started it is usually because of something else and the stacktrace usually shows it if you read it bottom up.

I would suggest adding it to your question, edit it and create a new formatted section for it. Also this bit you added is not the entire stack trace there should be a lot more.

ahh I see that you deleted the comment :)

@JorgeCampos - I just understood what you said! I am sorry. I edited the question and then added it.

There should be more than that after the null pointer on PersonService. It looks like you are missing more

@JorgeCampos - I updated it and posted the entire thread and not jst the error thread.

It is very weird that the exception is ending there... can you edit it and add the whole controller or at least the definition of the class? Is it annotated correctly?

@JorgeCampos - sure can! I made those edits and I also went ahead and added in the fxml page as well.

You posted Person.fxml but only posted the code that loads PersonsRecord.fxml. Post the code that loads the FXML that you posted in the question.

Probably off-topic, but I would strongly recommend not using Lombok with JavaFX. It assumes specific implementations of encapsulation that are contrary to the patterns typically used by JavaFX.

I made those updates. I forgot i had two fxml files for this program. Okay I can update that then.

Any chance of publishing this to a repo where we can download it and test it? Nothing is calling my attention with your configs so might need to run it to check

Don't post code externally to the site (it is against the rules of the site, for good reason). Create a simplified version of your project that reproduces the issue and post it in its entirety here. Mock up the repo (or just the service) with a simple class that generate hard-coded data.

repo.findAll() should return a list.

I am 99% sure, that your Service is null because your controller is not a Spring component. You marked it with @Component, which is a nice idea, but I would bet, that your controller is not created by Spring Boot, but by the FxmlLoader. This leads to "ignoring" the annotation, because there is a new Controller() in the FxmlLoader.

Example repos of mine which demonstrate the use of Spring Boot and JavaFx with Maven and Gradle: https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxSpringBootGradleApp
https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxSpringBootMavenApp
I would appreciate a star for supporting free open source.

@DavidWeber - Thank you for this explanation, the example and the information on where I can go from here. Seriously, I do appreciate it all. I do have one last question on an error I've been getting this morning that I cannot resolve. I did download your template and modified it for how I need it. I'll edit my question with the new error. Thank you.

@jewelsea - Ah thank you. I updated the error message. I looked at it for awhile yesterday and the applicationContext is null. I updated the error in the trace

@jewelsea  Okay, yeah that definitely allowed it to work. Thank you for noticing that. I should have paid better attention before posting that questions.                                                                  If you don't mind - I have one last question. Everytime a new fxml page needs to be loaded does the applicationContext need to be reinitialized?

Consolidated comments into an answer.  For further follow-up questions, consider asking new questions.

Explanation:
I am quite sure, that your service is null because your controller is not a Spring Component. You marked it with @Component, which is a nice idea, but because you use FXML I bet, that your controller is not created by Spring Boot, but by the FxmlLoader. This leads to "ignoring" the annotation, because the FxmlLoader creates a new instance of your controller by using the keyword new.
Example repos of mine which demonstrate the use of Spring Boot and JavaFx with Maven and Gradle.
JFX with Spring Boot and Gradle (better and more up to date)
JFX with Spring Boot and Maven
What to do next:
You have several options from here.

Easiest: Download the template and alter it to your needs. Everything is preconfigured and runs out of the box.
Mid workaround: Assign your Spring Boot Application context to a static variable and get your service in a non Spring Component by using Service service = springContext.getBean(Service.class).
Hardest: Restructure your code so your controller is a Spring Component (maybe build your own SpringFxmlLoader class).

Additional information:
Be aware when using Spring components. They can be stateless or stateful. In easier words: They can be a Singleton (scope singleton) or an own instance for every injection (scope prototype).

Thank you for this explanation, the example and the information on where I can go from here. Seriously, I do appreciate it all. I do have one last question on an error I've been getting this morning that I cannot resolve. I did download your template and modified it for how I need it. I'll edit my question with the new error. Thank you.

In the class FxApplicationStageIsReadyListener, convert the method JfxSpringBootStageIsReadyListener back to a constructor again. You changed it to a void method.

The information here is a replacement for my comments on the question and addresses follow-up questions from comments, so is supplemental rather than a direct answer.  Initial comments were regarding the originally asked question and may not reflect the information in the updated question.
Regarding Spring component scanning
Your controller is in package com.example.controllers.
A SpringBoot application, by default, will scan for annotated components in sibling and child packages. If your FXApplication class isn't in com.example, then com.example.controllers is not a child, and the controller won't be scanned and treated as an annotated Spring bean for dependency injection.
Regarding application instances
When you run
launch(FxApplication.class, args);

JavaFX will create an instance of FxApplication.class.
When you run this code, The Spring framework will start, after creating an instance of FxApplication.class returning the spring context that was initialized at startup.
springContext = SpringApplication.run(FxApplication.class); 

The springContext will be set on the instance created by JavaFX, but not the one created by Spring. The autowired personRepo in FXApplication will be set in the Spring-created instance, but not the JavaFX-created instance.
To prevent confusion around Spring and JavaFX application instances, I recommend using separate classes for each, as described in:

Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX (JPA Repo, Service)

FAQ

an error I've been getting this morning that I cannot resolve. I did download your template and modified it for how I need it. I'll edit my question with the new error.

"Exception in Application start method" is logged by the JavaFX framework code.
In your start method, wrap the code in try/catch to find out what is throwing the exception:
try { 
    /** your code **/ 
} (catch Throwable t) { 
    t.printStackTrace(); 
} 

Update your question to include the stack trace logged.
Your code differs from David's code. Your class is called FxApplicationStageIsReadyListener, so the constructor should have the same name. Instead, you made the constructor a regular method and gave it a void return type public void JfxSpringBootStageIsReadyListener -> it will never be invoked, and its fields (including the applicationContext) will never be initialized.

Everytime a new fxml page needs to be loaded does the applicationContext need to be initialized?

No.
The application context will act like a singleton-scoped spring bean. There is only one and it is only initialized once at Spring application startup.  If the application context cannot be initialized by Spring, then Spring will fail to start.
Later operations on the context will update the internal state of the existing instance.  As long as you have a reference to the context instance that you retrieved after application startup, it will already be initialized and up to date.
You use the context to create and return a controller bean:
fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(applicationContext::getBean);

A controller bean is the Spring-created and initialized controller instance.
The controller should be prototype-scoped, as in this answer:

Adding Spring Dependency Injection in JavaFX (JPA Repo, Service)
@Component 
@Scope("prototype") 
public class DemoController { 
    // ...
}



Then new controller instances are created each time you need one, rather than using a singleton controller.

Good information! I updated the Git repo a little bit!

Thank you for this explanation. I really appreciate all your time with this issue and helping me understand the Springboot and Javafx integration and setting up the dependency injection. I am getting a separate error that I'll create a new question for. Seriously thank you again for all this help.
